# Running program when catch occurs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to download images using [this package](https://gitlab.com/demsking/image-downloader) - but sometimes, one of these images is corrupted. Here, one of the two sample images is corrupted and I'm adding a Math.random() to simulate this case. I'm now trying to restart the program once the `.catch()` occurs - the thing is the program runs infinitely then. How can I solve this?

My code is:

```
let imgArrays = ["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dc/Gigi1.jpg", "https://mms.businesswire.com/media/20211119005773/fr/929256/5/Aries_Linden_mechanical_completion_11-19-2021.jpg"]

const runingImage = () => {


    const url = imgArrays[Math.floor(imgArrays.length * Math.random())];
    const path = 'img/image.jpg'
    options = {
        url: url,
        dest: path
    }
    download.image(options)
        .then(({
            filename
        }) => {
            console.log('Saved to', filename)
        }).catch(
            (err) => {
                console.log("running again");
                return runingImage();
            })
}

runingImage();
```

When I run it, it now only gives me:

```
running again
running again
...
Until I stops the console.
```

Comment: You have a semicolon at your url

Comment: If i navigate to that url i get a 404

Comment: @ManosKounelakis bad formatting, fixed. For the 404, I'm able to open both images on my end, simply by copy/pasting the link into a browser tab.

Comment: as @ManosKounelakis said, remove semicolons from your urls. when you use such url based programming, it is best you validate them before putting in your code.

Comment: @ManosKounelakis, they're removed.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the return statement. It should be like:

```js
let imgArrays = ["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dc/Gigi1.jpg", "https://mms.businesswire.com/media/20211119005773/fr/929256/5/Aries_Linden_mechanical_completion_11-19-2021.jpg"]
    
const runingImage = () => {
  const url = imgArrays[Math.floor(imgArrays.length * Math.random())]
  const path = 'img/image.jpg'
  options = {
      url: url,
      dest: path
  }
  download.image(options)
    .then(({
        filename
    }) => {
        console.log('Saved to', filename)
    }).catch(
        (err) => {
          console.log("running again")
    })
}

runingImage()
```

Comment: this does not restart the program - calling runingImage() when the catch() is resolved.

Comment: Btw i'll just try and see it myself

Comment: Nope, I don't think there is any resolutionto your query. Errors are bound to be corrected, so it is a mechanism of JS, to stop a running application, so that no more problems, like memory leaks, arise due to it. Don't assume me wrong, but it is how it is.

Answer (score 0):

It is unfortunate that you stepped into a trap all programmers have fallen (and still falling) at some point: **missing files/folders**

when you are still in the development stage, always print errors in catch statements. this is what you would get and eventually solve the problem yourself:

`console.log(err)`

*ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'img/image.jpg'*

also there is this little mistake you are doing. you are creating a `void` type function and try to `return` its value which is always `undefined`

solution:

1. create an `img` folder in the directory you put this file of yours.
2. remove `return` word inside catch block leaving only `runingImage();`